# Not able to access init.sh file in docker

Tags: docker, shell, docker-container, localstack

I am running localstack in docker container and in localstack docker container i have a init-aws.sh file  at /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/ location with executable permissions.
but while runnning app i am getting this error in container logs :

```
[  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh'
```

You can see file permissions here in SS :
[image]

I also tried to execute file in container and here is output :
[image]

I am not sure what's wrong with this file. Any help will be appreciated.

Docker file :

```
services:
  test-localstack:
      container_name: test-localstack
      image: localstack/localstack
      ports:
          - '4566:4566' # LocalStack Gateway
          - '4510-4559:4510-4559' # external services port range
      environment:
          - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
          - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      volumes:
          - './localstack/init.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh'
          - '${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack'
          - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile once?

Comment: Check the file's interpreter. You'll get this error if the interpreter (or its dynamic loader) is missing.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal, added docker file content